# How to create a foreign key in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it okay to write as follows to define a foreign key when creating tables in SQLite?

// income table create statement

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_income = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_income
        + "(" + KEY_IID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_AMOUNT + " TEXT," +KEY_ID + " INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TABLE_user(uid)" 
        + KEY_INCOMEDATE + " DATETIME" +KEY_INCOMETYPE + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close but there are still some syntax problems.

- You need commas between column specifications. Missing in two places before `KEY_INCOMEDATE` and `KEY_INCOMETYPE`.
- The syntax for a foreign key in in a column specification would be just `REFERENCES`, like `KEY_ID + " INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_User(uid)"`.
- Alternatively you can define the foreign key in a table constraint using the `FOREIGN KEY (column_name) REFERENCES other_table(other_column)` syntax. Table constraints are placed after the column specifications.

Example:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_income = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_income
    + "(" + KEY_IID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_AMOUNT + " TEXT," +KEY_ID + " INTEGER REFERENCES TABLE_user(uid)," 
    + KEY_INCOMEDATE + " DATETIME," +KEY_INCOMETYPE + " TEXT" + ")";
```

For the alternative approach, see Szymon's answer.

To make foreign key constraints enforced, remember to set e.g. `PRAGMA foreign_keys = 'on'`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand why to put PRAGMA foreign_keys = 'on' ? I am a beginner in android

Answer (score 1):

You should put your foreign key definition at the end, after the columns list:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_income = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_income
        + "(" + KEY_IID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_AMOUNT + " TEXT," +KEY_ID + " INTEGER," 
        + KEY_INCOMEDATE + " DATETIME," + KEY_INCOMETYPE + " TEXT, "
        +"FOREIGN KEY (" + KEY_ID + ") REFERENCES TABLE_user(uid))";
```